# Where is the screenshot property list now located in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, terminal, screen-capture, preferences

Previously, the screenshot property list could be found at:

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist`

In Mavericks, this file no longer exists. In the past, I used to be able to manipulate the location and image type of screenshots using the .plist mentioned above. Where are these values now stored? Do I now need to create the plist in order to manipulate these variables, IE:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/folder/of/my/choice
```

To be sure this was not an issue with my user account, I created a new admin. account and tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the plist seems to no longer exist by default, however I have changed my save location using the same command that you provided in your question and it's worked fine — the plist *is* read by OS X after logout and login.

Comment: grgarside, appreciate the response (and reassurance i'm not going crazy!). Out of curiosity, do you know where these variables now natively reside (without creation of a new property list to manipulate that which clearly is present somewhere)?

Comment: why would it no longer exist by default?

Comment: @njboot I'm not sure — I presume it'd be hardcoded into the app.

Comment: @Buscar I guess because it's no longer required.

Comment: So how come I have it?

Comment: @Buscar I presume either you or an app has created it by changing a setting.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at my MBA with 10.9.2 it is still in the

> User/myname/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist

As it turns out, the .plist will only exist (be created) if you modify the screencapture settings, like location to save and others.

Comment: Buscar: thanks for the reply. This file neither exists in my user account, nor a vanilla admin user account I created to double check that it wasn't an issue related to my own account. Could this be a system wide issue?

Comment: it could....it should have been there by default. unless you deleted it and did not restart allowing it to recreate it self.

Comment: Forgot to reboot. But I just checked, no luck.